# Asp.net WebApi POST request does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api method which is as follows,

```
[Route("api/Nltk")]
[HttpPost]
public string Create([FromBody]string text)
{
    string result = "Error";
    //Assign result here
    return result;
}
```

When I make a POST request I get `404 - File or directory not found.` error. While other methods (which are all GET methods) in the same api work just fine. For further detail `http://ozgurakpinar.net/api/Nltk` is the complete url.

The following is one of the methods I've tried, so far.

```
 var values = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "text", "This is a relatively short sentence." },
    };
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var result = client.PostAsync("http://ozgurakpinar.net/api/Nltk", content).Result;
```

**Edit:** After I added the FromBody attribute the method is finally called, but the value of `text` is null.

Comment: The format is correct. Looks like url really "not found" :)

Comment: @АнтониоАнтуан But I just published it and other web api methods work just fine. But all the other ones are GET methods=) I am stuck with the post.

Comment: try this: https://www.getpostman.com. It allows you to make custom requests, e.g. POST. Also, Chrome plugin is available

Comment: @АнтониоАнтуан You are right. I will edit my question because it is certainly not about Python at all.

Comment: How you are posting, plz add that code/approach also.

Comment: @AnilKumar I added the details now.

Comment: Have you done all required configuration to make Attribute Routing work , bascically  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); you can refer details here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Where is the value of `text` coming from, a form or the url? Your parameter needs to be bound.

Comment: @AnilKumar  I did it inside WebApiConfig.cs file. My other GET methods which also use attribute routing works.

Comment: It's null because you need to use `FromUri` and not `FromBody`.

Comment: @DrewKennedy When I change FormBody to FormUri the method is not called this time. Debug is not entered the method.

Comment: How are you testing your url? Google's REST client? Try testing it as such: `http://ozgurakpinar.net/api/Nltk?text=mystring`

Comment: @DrewKennedy After I got stuck with this problem, I am testing it locally. On my own computer, debugging it. Get methos work perfectly but post is such a pain in the ass.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102267/discussion-between-drew-kennedy-and-ozgur).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FromBody value get null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837844/frombody-value-get-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are giving a name to your value then actually you are looking for a class with that member. In your case you are posting to a method which accept a `class having a text member of string type`.

If you need to post to a method having a string parameter then no need to give it a name. Below is working code.

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string> {{ "", "This is a relatively short sentence." }};
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var result = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:49923/api/Nltk", content).Result;
            Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: This worked. But I still think POST is problematic in Web Api. A dictionary where **key** is an empty string? How come it can hash an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you may have a typo. It should be [FromBody] not [FormBody].

Secondly, you need to append an "=" before your content string.

ie:

```
client.PostAsync("http://ozgurakpinar.net/api/Nltk", "=" + content)
```

Comment: I was actually using full name System.Web.Http.FromBody and I just perceived it wrong. But it is correct in the code. My question is how can I concatenate "=" with a HttpContent type? content is not a string.